# Active Record in Yii2, Joining multiple table, find the rating of a thread, and retrieve the rating in ListView

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am confused with how to retrieve data that has been averaged after joining multiple tables.

Problem:
I have 3 tables i want to join, User, Thread, and Rate.
I need all data from the tables and for rate table, i need to do average operation to get the rating value

My code is:
MyController looks like this:

```
  public function actionHome(){

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Thread::retrieveAll(),            
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' =>5,
            ],

        ]);

        return $this->render('home', ['listDataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
    }
```

My active record class (model class) looks like this:

```
public static function retrieveAll(){



  return  Self::find()->joinWith('user')
    ->joinWith('rate')
    ->select(['AVG(rate.rating) as rating, thread.*, user.*'])
    ->groupBy('rate.thread_id');    
}

public  function getUser(){
         return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);

}

public function getRate(){
    return $this->hasMany(Rate::className(), ['thread_id' =>'thread_id']);
}
```

Retrieve all is used in the data provider query
My home class looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?= ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $listDataProvider,
        'options' => [
            'tag' => 'div',
            'class' => 'list-wrapper',
            'id' => 'list-wrapper',
        ],
        'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}",

        'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            return $this->render('_list_thread',['model' => $model]);
        }, 
        'pager' => [
            'firstPageLabel' => 'first',
            'lastPageLabel' => 'last',
            'nextPageLabel' => 'next',
            'prevPageLabel' => 'previous',
            'maxButtonCount' => 3,
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

my item for the listview looks like this:

```
<article>
    <div class="box col-md-12">


        <div class="row">
                <?= Html::a($model->title, Url::to('thread/index.php?id='. $model->thread_id))?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p> <?= $model->content ?> </p> 
        </div>

        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <?= StarRating::widget([
                'name' => 'rating_2',
                'value' => 2.5,
                'readonly' => true,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'showCaption' => false,
                    'min' => 0,
                    'max' => 5,
                    'step' => 1,
                    'size' => 'xs',

                ]])?>
        </div class="col-md-7" align="center center-vertical">
            <p align="right" style="font-size:8px">Created by   <?= $model->user->first_name?>  <?=$model->user->last_name?> at <?= $model->date_created ?></p>


        </div>
        </div>


    <br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</article>
```

I can retrieve $model->user->first_name and lst_name but i cannot retrieve $model->rate->rating

Any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 3):

```
$this::select('AVG(rate.rating) as rating',*)->innerJoin('rate','your codition on you have to take a join')->innerJoin('thread','your codition on you have to take a join')->all()->groupBy('rate.thread_id');
```

Comment: there is no method named select, i did it this way
Self::select('AVG(rate.rating) as rating','*')->innerJoin('user', ['id' => 'user_id'])->innerJoin('rate',['thread_id' =>'thread_id'])->groupBy('rate.thread_id');